# Bandwidth shaping and virtual network layer/interface - Windows + .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, networking

I've recently started my new private project.

The main goal which I want to achieve is to **limit the bandwidth** on Windows. At first, I'd like to shape the traffic for all system connection, without limiting per application. (I'm not interested in implementing QoS.)

I thought that a good solution for that matter it to **create a virtual network driver/layer/interface** and to put the whole connection through it. If you think that would be a good solution, please can you help me or suggest how to achieve it?

Feel free to ask more specific questions or just to answer for mine.;)

Thanks,
Andrew.

Comment: What you are describing is known as a "traffic shaping tool". There are many avaialble for Windows. Do an internet serach for "network traffic shaping on windows". There's some free ones you could use to get an idea of how they do it.  If you are writing driver code, you will be writing it in C/C++, not .net.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. Of course, I know what it is called and I had done some researches. There are some examples, but I want to create my own tool for my own purpose **as I described**. 

I'm aware of using C/C++ in drivers development, that's not a problem for me. 

I need to create virtual network interface -> pass the whole traffic through it -> be able to limit the bandwidth (i.e. only for upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a module in [fireBwall](http://www.firebwall.com).  Its a modular Windows firewall/network framework.  All you would need to do is make a module that detects the current bandwidth(there is a [BandwidthCounter](http://code.google.com/p/firebwall/source/browse/trunk/passthru/Tabs/BandwidthCounter.cs) class that may be helpful in the source) then run Thread.Sleep to get the bandwidth to where you want it.  If you'd like one of the fireBwall developers to do it, I'm sure they'd be happy to if you requested on the [forums](http://firebwall.proboards.com).  fireBwall modules can be written in .NET, so it would not be very difficult.